Nested dependencies in mono-repo not found even though they're there
I have a monorepo that uses several local packages via links in package.json
The setup works fine except for one issue, Sequelize. Sequelize has problems if you have multiple packages including it
as it operates as a singleton and you end up with multiple singletons so operations fail.
I've been trying to work out if there's a way to get this right with "peerDependencies" or similar but I can't quite get it to function.
The packages are separate git repos, setup with package.json with all the right details.
They are linked via npm/yarn link in package.json, like so:
"dependencies": {
  "app-server": "0.1.0",
  ...
},
"resolutions": {
  "app-server": "portal:/Users/tobytremayne/work/app-server",
  ...
}

Packages:
app-server (nodejs: handles nodejs generic functionality)

imports app-shared
ORMProvider -> imports Sequelize

app-shared (vanilla: shared events, constants, utils)
app-rc (react: react component library)

imports app-shared

app-cli (nodejs: cmdline tools and codegen used in development)

imports app-shared
CodeGen imports sequelize for DataTypes

The MonoRepo:
/
[Package.json name="projectmono"]

imports app-shared
imports app-cli
imports app-server for FileManager, CodeGen (which imports DataTypes from sequelize)
imports sequelize

/server (runs ORM Provider which uses sequelize for queries, also has models and other files that import DataTypes et al from sequelize)
[Package.json name="appserver"]- imports app-shared

import app-server
imports sequelize

/client (react client)
[Package.json name="appclient"]

imports app-shared

Package.json tree looks like this:

/ [Package.json name="projectmono"]

peerDependencies:
dependencies:

app-shared [Package.json name="appshared"]
app-cli [Package.json name="appcli"]


devDependencies

sequelize-cli


/server [Package.json name="projectserver"]

peerDependencies:

sequelize
sequelize-cli


dependencies:

app-shared [Package.json name="appshared"]
app-server [Package.json name="appserver"]




/client [Package.json name="projectclient"]

dependencies:
app-shared [Package.json name="appshared"]





The root of the monorepo's package.json has a resolutions section that looks like this:
"resolutions": {
  "app-shared": "portal:/Users/tobytremayne/work/app-shared",
  "app-server": "portal:/Users/tobytremayne/work/app-server",
  "app-rc": "portal:/Users/tobytremayne/work/app-rc",
  "app-cli": "portal:/Users/tobytremayne/work/app-cli"
}

Essentially the monorepo imports our app-server package, which instantiates sequelize as usual.
The cli package also imports sequelize in order to get at it's DataTypes, but if both have sequelize
as a dependency, then at server runtime there are two versions of sequelize in memory and things fail.
I thought I could just make sequelize a peer dependency for both app-server and app-cli, and the monorepo would install sequelize in /node_modules for both to use.
This lets the server works and perform ORM stuff, but when trying to use the CLi it reports not being able to find the sequelize package from monorepo -> app-cli -> app-server -> CodeGen
unless I add it as a dependency in app-server.
If I make sequelize a peerdependency for all the packages and have the monorepo depend on it, shouldn't that work for the monorepo -> app-cli -> app-server -> Sequelize imports?
It seems as though when I run the cli, it operates in it's own context, and it's subsequent import of app-server looks for sequelize perhaps under /node_modules/app-server/node_modules?
Because even when it's installed as a dependency of the monorepo root and app-server and app-cli both have sequelize as a peer dependency, it doesn't find it in /node_modules.
I was hoping to work it this way as during deployment, app-server is pulled out by itself, and so needs sequelize in it's own package.json so it gets installed when there's no
monorepo parent workspace, yet the monorepo code obviously uses sequelize plenty in order to access DataTypes and such.
I'm using nodejs 20.11 and yarn 4.0.0. on MacOS.
